# Spring MVC Form Checkbox and Label do not line up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a `<form:checkbox>` to the left of a `<form:label>` using the code below:

```
<form:checkbox path="acceptTerms" id="acceptTerms"/>
<form:label path="acceptTerms">Accept Terms</form:label>
```

However, when I do that, it looks like this:

[image]

I have tried display:inline, float:left, and everything else i can find. But it just doesn't work.

The HTML code generated is:

```
<input id="acceptTerms" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="_acceptTerms" value="on">
<label for="acceptTerms">Accept Terms</label>
```

I appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: I've changed your tags from spring to css, because this isn't really a spring question -- I'm a spring expert so you can trust me on this, spring doesn't have any control of your page design, it only generates the input and label tags. You need to work on your CSS to fix this, and to that end, can you please show us your css, and the bits of html around the form, and the link that loads your css in the first place?

Comment: And the answer, btw, is to use a flexbox, but to do that you'll ahve to add classes to your form elements. Check this out: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @EngineerDollery - There was actually some hidden CSS import (in a file in a file kind of thing) that caused the issue. It was setting: `clear: left; margin; 1px 10px 0px 0px; text-align: right`

This was the issue. I just overrode those inline and it fixed it. Please add your "confirm with your CSS" as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably isn't in spring, but rather is an issue with your CSS. You should check in firebug (or something similar) to see what's being loaded, and what is affecting your control and label. You should then be able to pinpoint the code you need to change.